# Windows Sandbox Version Upgrade

Tags: windows, windows-sandbox

How do you upgrade the version of Windows running in Windows sandbox?  I have upgraded to Windows 20H2 but the Sandbox version is 2004.

Comment: How exactly did you determine Windows Sandbox was version 2004?

Comment: Running winver in the sandbox is an easy way.

Answer (score 2):

A Microsoft Software Engineer [replied to this same question on Reddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/k0olaw/how_to_updateconfigure_windows_10_sandbox/gfuixu2/):

> The sandbox benefits from updates that the host receives (and this is why it has no servicing stack of its own). Even if the UI does not always reflect the updated state, every new Sandbox starts from the same binaries the host is using.

> In general the Sandbox will always be in the host's updated file state with limited exception.

Comment: Interesting. Weird how the UI does not always reflect the updates that it's supposedly running.